# Relationship between the integral of $\sin(x)$ and the integral of $\ln(\sin(x))$.

Tags: definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

If $$\int_a^b \sin(x) dx = \int_a^b \cos(x) dx, $$
does this always imply the following?$$\int_a^b \ln(\sin(x)) dx = \int_a^b \ln(\cos(x)) dx $$
My attempt on this is using the definition of definite integral to transform the question to the following but couldn’t go further. If
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \sin\left(\frac{b-a}n\right)= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \cos\left(\frac{b-a}n\right),
$$
then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{i=1}^n \sin\left(\frac{b-a}n\right)= \lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{i=1}^n \cos\left(\frac{b-a}n\right)  $$

Comment: No - the hypothesis you have is incorrect at the start. If the integral of two functions on the same interval are equal, then the functions agree almost everywhere - this is certainly not true for sine and cosine.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I think OP meant _for some $a, b$_.

Comment: Suppose $0 < a < b < \pi/2$ so that $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are both positive on $[a,b]$. Now,  if $\int_a^b \sin(x) dx = \int_a^b \cos(x) dx$, show that $a+b=\pi/2$.

Comment: @user2661923 Any increasing function passing through $(0,0)$ and $(\pi/2,1)$ takes on the same values as sine in one-to-one correspondance, so that is not sufficient.

Comment: @DavidP Do you mean that it is insufficient because the conclusion of the conjecture now involves points where the function is no longer finite? That is an interesting idea.  I was on shaky grounds anyway with my comments, so I have deleted them.

Answer (score 2):

We can easily calculate the integrals of $\sin$ and $\cos$ explicitly; why don’t we do that?
$\int_a^b \sin(x) dx = \cos(a) - \cos(b)$ and $\int_a^b \cos(x) dx = \sin(b) - \sin(a)$. Equating the two expressions, we have
$$\sin(a) + \cos(a) = \sin(b) + \cos(b).$$
Recall $\sin(x) + \cos(x) = \sqrt{2} \sin(x + \pi / 4)$. So, we have $\sin(a + \pi / 4) = \sin(b + \pi / 4)$.
Note $\sin(x) = \sin(y) \iff y = x + 2 k \pi \text{ or } y = \pi - x + 2 k \pi$ for some integer $k$. Therefore, either
$$b + \pi / 4 = a + \pi / 4 + 2k \pi \implies b = a + 2k \pi,$$
or
$$b + \pi / 4 = \pi - a - \pi / 4 + 2 k \pi \implies b = \pi / 2 - a + 2k \pi.$$

In the first case, both $\sin$ and $\cos$ go through an integer multiple of full cycles on $[a, b]$. In the latter case,
$$\cos(b - t) = \cos(\pi / 2 - (a + t) + 2k \pi) = \sin(a + t),$$
meaning $\cos$ is a flipped image of $\sin$ on $[a, b]$. In either of these cases, $\sin$ and $\cos$ actually have the same shape after cutting and pasting, or flipping. This means if we take each of $\sin$ and $\cos$ as a whole on $[a, b]$ by integrating, they should look the same. Consequently, we have the result: for any function $f$,
$$\int_a^b f(\sin(x)) dx = \int_a^b f(\cos(x)) dx.$$
The desired equation where $f = \ln$ is just a special case.

Comment: And good luck computing $\ln\sin x$ at, say, $x=0$

Comment: @user58697 Well, I should have been more clear that *as long as the integrals make sense*, the equality holds. That is, if you want $f = \ln$, you have stronger conditions on $a$ and $b$, but that still makes the equality true.